# having a javascript circular reference issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, circular-reference

I have a function **createminor4**(arr, tourney)
it basically splits *arr* into 4 groups of 8 and swaps them into *tourney* 1 group at a time.
from there it pushes into the four{} which has 4 keys with empty arrays.

I've stepped through it in chrome and after the first group pushes correctly the next group overwrites the previous one even though I am pushing to different keys in the four{}.
I am ending up with a circular reference and don't understand what I am doing wrong.

*The createMinor4() should return:
`four {
"A":[["Lava Lamps", ..."shooters"],["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["e", "f"],["g"]],
"B":[["Yellow Dragons", ... "water pistols"],["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["e", "f"],["g"]],
"C":[["Snakes", ... "Hawks"],["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["e", "f"],["g"]],
"D":[["Gamers", ... "worms"],["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["e", "f"],["g"]]}`

```js
let players4 = [
  "Lava Lamps", "Jarheads", "Cloud Gazerz", "Cobras", "Red Ravens", "Leaders", "Destroyers", "shooters",
  "Yellow Dragons", "Whales", "fearwolves", "Hitters", "red rebels", "Knights", "cute gremlins", "water pistols",
  "Snakes", "Ravens", "Chariots-of-Hell", "Predators", "Assassins", "Gladiators", "Broncos", "Hawks",
  "Gamers", "Slickers", "Freeze", "Rabbits", "Holy Rollers", "Crusaders", "FireHawks", "Worms"
]
let minorTourny = [
  ["t1", "t2"],
  ["t3", "t4"],
  ["t5", "t6"],
  ["t7", "t8"],
  ["a", "b"],
  ["c", "d"],
  ["e", "f"],
  ["g"]
];

function createMinor4(arr, tourney) {
  let q = arr.length * .25;
  let s = 0;
  let p = 1;
  let g = 4;
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  let z = 0;

  let four = {
    "A": [],
    "B": [],
    "C": [],
    "D": []
  }
  //while 4 > 0
  while (g > s) {
    do {
      let loadTeam = tourney[x].splice(y, 1, arr[z]);
      if (z === 0) {
        loadTeam;
        y++;
      } else if (z % 2 == 0) {
        loadTeam;
        y = 1;
      } else if (z % 2 !== 0) {
        loadTeam;
        y = 0;
        x++;
      }
      z++;
    }
    while (z < q) // while 0 < 8
    if (g === 4) {
      four.A.push(tourney);
    } else if (g === 3) {
      four.B.push(tourney);
    } else if (g === 2) {
      four.C.push(tourney);
    } else if (g === 1) {
      four.D.push(tourney);
    }
    arr.splice(0, q)
    g--;
    p++;
    z = 0;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
  }
  return four
}
console.log(createMinor4(players4, minorTourny))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `splice` on Array it will also change original Array that is why you `players4` and `minorTourny` are not same after `createMinor4` function call
You can use `Deep copy`
When you use deep copy it will no longer have reference of original Array
[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

```js
let players4 = [
  "Lava Lamps", "Jarheads", "Cloud Gazerz", "Cobras", "Red Ravens", "Leaders", "Destroyers", "shooters",
  "Yellow Dragons", "Whales", "fearwolves", "Hitters", "red rebels", "Knights", "cute gremlins", "water pistols",
  "Snakes", "Ravens", "Chariots-of-Hell", "Predators", "Assassins", "Gladiators", "Broncos", "Hawks",
  "Gamers", "Slickers", "Freeze", "Rabbits", "Holy Rollers", "Crusaders", "FireHawks", "Worms"
]
let minorTourny = [
  ["t1", "t2"],
  ["t3", "t4"],
  ["t5", "t6"],
  ["t7", "t8"],
  ["a", "b"],
  ["c", "d"],
  ["e", "f"],
  ["g"]
];

function createMinor4(_arr, _tourney) {
  const arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_arr)); // Use Deep copy
  const tourney = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_tourney)); // Use Deep copy
  let q = arr.length * .25;
  let s = 0;
  let p = 1;
  let g = 4;
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  let z = 0;

  let four = {
    "A": [],
    "B": [],
    "C": [],
    "D": []
  }
  //while 4 > 0
  while (g > s) {
    do {
      let loadTeam = tourney[x].splice(y, 1, arr[z]);
      if (z === 0) {
        loadTeam;
        y++;
      } else if (z % 2 == 0) {
        loadTeam;
        y = 1;
      } else if (z % 2 !== 0) {
        loadTeam;
        y = 0;
        x++;
      }
      z++;
    }
    while (z < q) // while 0 < 8
    if (g === 4) {
      four.A.push(tourney);
    } else if (g === 3) {
      four.B.push(tourney);
    } else if (g === 2) {
      four.C.push(tourney);
    } else if (g === 1) {
      four.D.push(tourney);
    }
    arr.splice(0, q)
    g--;
    p++;
    z = 0;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
  }
  return four
}
console.log(createMinor4(players4, minorTourny))
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave this a shot but still the same issue. However, it was nice to be made aware of deep copy. I've updated my question to be a little clearer.

Comment: Actually this works, it just needed to be declared later in the code. just before the if statements that control the .push(). Thanks again.